# How to do file_get_contents() from directory other than __DIR__?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending an email using PHPMailer and this works fine:

```
$mail->Subject = "My Email Subject";
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('emailcontent.html'), __DIR__);
$mail->send();
```

The file 'emailcontent.html' is in the current directory and it works.

Now I want to move the 'emailcontent.html' file into subdirectory 'emails/emailcontent.html'.

I tried this ...

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('emailcontent.html'), __DIR__.'/emails/');
```

... and this ...

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('/emails/emailcontent.html'), __DIR__);
```

... but neither worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that `emailcontent.html` was in the current directory and now it will be in `emails/emailcontent.html`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: The location of the html file must be made know to file_get_contents(). The second param to msgHtml is only measnt for relative resource references from within the html blob; http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_msgHTML

Comment: Assuming the `emails` directory is below the Current Directory I dont see why `file_get_contents('emails/emailcontent.html')` does not work.

Comment: So as **does not work** is a terrible description of an issue, can you tell us exactly what is not working, with error message, or something to help us heere

Comment: Using relative bounce arounds like this are always prone to running into issues. And doing `'/emails/emailcontent.html'` means that dir is at the ROOT of your entire system.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the help ... you're right I should have been clearer.  The error message was 'Mailer Error: Message body empty' ... so basically it couldn't find the file.  I was using `/emails/emailcontent.html' and that failed (I corrected my posting with the correct problem).  Following your suggestion it is now working with 'emails/emailcontent.html'.

Comment: Haaa Always difficult to debug `What I ment to write` code. :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks again, I'll be more thorough when posting questions in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RiggsFolly for straightening me out ... the problem was an errant `/`.

This works:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('emails/emailcontent.html'), __DIR__);
```

Comment: for some reason using the full path in place of __DIR__ doesn't work, you need to add the subfolder in the file name (as is the case in this answer).